# Split comma separated string getting a " "

Tags: c#

I have a comma separated string array like

,/pictures/222.jpg,/pictures/inbannerbg2.jpg

While I split the array I am getting a  " " value first.and it insert in to the table as null value.
How can we remove this.

here is my code

build to comma sepparated array

```
Session["image"] = Session["image"] + ",/pictures/" + filename;
        img = Session["image"].ToString();
```

Split Array

```
img = Convert.ToString(Session["image"]);
        string[] img_split = img.Split(',');
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: here is the code img = Convert.ToString(Session["image"]);
        string[] img_split = img.Split(',');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method overload that allows you to specify a `StringSplitOptions`:

```
string[] img_split = img.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can read about it in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Since your string has a comma at the beginning of it, the first element of the array returned by `Split()` will be an empty string. Here we tell it to drop the empty string.